# How to disable comboBox autoselection attribute when Textupdated

Tags: combobox, autocomplete

I want a comboBox to autocomplete and I found the below code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace testcomboBox
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<string> listOnit = new List<string>() { "Stephen_Curry", "Kevin_Durant", "Draymond_Green", "Zaza_Pachulia","Gerald Green" };
        List<string> listSearchUpdate = new List<string>();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void comboBox1_TextUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            listSearchUpdate.Clear();
            foreach (var item in listOnit)
            {
                if (item.Contains(comboBox1.Text))
                {
                    listSearchUpdate.Add(item);
                }
            }
            comboBox1.Items.AddRange(listSearchUpdate.ToArray());
            comboBox1.SelectionStart = comboBox1.Text.Length;
            Cursor = Cursors.Default;
            comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The code has a bug When type letter "G",the comboBox immediately autoselects "Gerald Green" and fills it to the edit control of the comboBox,but if you type "G" again,the edit control just fine to show "G" and pop up list of "Draymond_Green" and "Gerald Green". So how to disable autoselection function when type string in the edit control of the comboBox?

Answer (score 0):

refer to this link[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39924888/c-sharp-preventing-custom-combobox-from-autoselecting-an-item)

I revised code below and it is ok.

```
private void comboBox1_TextUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            listSearchUpdate.Clear();
            string strTemp = string.Empty;
            foreach (var item in listOnit)
            {
                if (item.Contains(comboBox1.Text))
                {
                    strTemp = comboBox1.Text;
                    listSearchUpdate.Add(item);
                }
            }
            comboBox1.Items.AddRange(listSearchUpdate.ToArray());
            comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;
            comboBox1.SelectionStart = strTemp.Length;
            Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }
```